# What exactly is simple consistency?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Now yes, I know the definition:

> A sequence of estimators $\{T_n\}$of $\tau(\theta)$ are consistent if for every $\epsilon > 0$
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}P[|T_n-\tau(\theta)|\leq\epsilon]=1 \\\text{ or} \\
> \lim_{n\to\infty}P[|T_n-\tau(\theta)|>\epsilon]=0
> $$
>   for every $\theta \in \Omega$

But what is this telling me? I'm having trouble translating this into something I can grasp, remember and/or even understand correctly. By taking the $\lim$ of $T_n$ we get a higher probability ofgetting closer to the true $\theta$? Should I look at this at some sort of convergence of $T_n \overset{p}{\to} \tau(\theta) $? Why do we use the word consistent? What is so 'consistent' about it?

Comment: Consistency is indeed just convergence in probability towards the true parameter $\tau(\theta)$.

Comment: Why "simple consistency" and not simply "consistency" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to know about the concept of consistency. Note that consistency is a large sample property of estimators. Here we consider the sequence of estimators $\{T_n\}$ to estimate parameter $\tau (\theta)$ where $n$ is the sample size. As the sample size $n\to \infty$, the data $(x_1,x_2, \dots,x_n)$ are practically the whole population  and it is intuitively appealing to desire that a good sequence of estimators  $\{T_n\}$ should be one for which values of the estimator tend to concentrate near $\tau(\theta)$ as the sample size increases. If $n \to \infty$ and the values of an  estimator are not very close to $\tau (\theta)$ *that is* the performance of the estimator is not good, then the performance of the estimator will be bad incase the sample size is small.

Comment: But when do estimators not 'converge' to $\tau(\theta)$? It seems as though they should always do so, given that they are a 'good' estimator. Is the MSE and consistency a good way of 'testing' an estimator $T_n$ ?

Comment: @WiseStrawberry: Estimators not converge to $\tau(\theta)$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}P[|T_n-\tau(\theta)|\leq\epsilon] \neq 1$. And yes minimum MSE and consistency are a good way of testing an estimator.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $T_n$ is a random variable. Thus, the two pair of equivalent equations are telling us that, as $n$ tends to infinity, events where $T_n$ deviates from the true value $\tau(\theta)$ occur less often and in the limit the deviations occur over a set of measure zero.

Comment: So consistent in the fact that deviations tend to occur less often. but is there a difference between 'simple consistent' and 'consistent'?

Comment: This is the first time I am hearing about 'simple consistent'. Yes, consistent = deviations occur less often.

Comment: because the book/teacher uses 'simple' every now and again. so I was confused. But thank you